# Paste image into ckeditor

Tags: image, upload, ckeditor, paste

I am trying to get the abiltiy to paste an image from the clipboard into  ckeditor.

It is unclear if I can do this with the standard download or if I have to download additional plugin(s).

I tried to follow the various plugins but it seems quite complicated as some of the plugins have dependencies and some of those dependencies have their own dependencies!

I then tried the ckbuilder route but after I highlighted the plugin that said it lets you paste in images from the clipboard I could not see the plugin in the resulting download.

Lastly I could not find any info on how you enable plugins - am I right in thinking you have to edit the config.js file or is it something else?

Thanks!

Ed

Comment: See "Uploading Dropped and Pasted Images" section in [this](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html) official sample.

Comment: ckeditor is great. BUT it has the most cryptic, complicated and un-user friendly "help" i've ever seen. I'm on the same boat: i did exactly the same thing as you but the upload doesnt work and it seems like i need "upload.php" which doesnt seem to be bundled with it (WHY?) and the instructions for the file upload is just an endless cryptic  bits of incomplete information "click this to know more". I'm sure in the end it tells you that you just have to write some assembly code to make it work. so frustrating

Answer (score 1):

To support uploading image you need to add [upload image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage) plugin with all its dependencies, which is not included in any standard package. To include all dependencies automatically use the [builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder). Plugins included into your custom package created with builder are included into the `ckeditor.js` file and load automatically. To make image upload works you need to define the [uploadUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-uploadUrl) configuration option additionally.

Also note that only Firefox support pasting files. On other brosers you can drag and drop file or an image from the image processor (Paint, Gimp, Photoshop, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for this - I have used the builder.  I think it has downloaded the dependencies but it is hard to be sure.

Comment: Please can you let mek now where I set uploadURL and what I should set it to - should it be a folder or a .php script?

Comment: Yes, `uploadURL` should point script which will handle uploaded files and return a JSON response. See this guide to get details: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload

Comment: Thanks - where do set the uploadURL - index.html or config.js?

Comment: I tried putting it in config.js then did a refresh but when I tried to paste an image I got the following in console:Error: Upload URL for the Upload Image feature was not defined. For more information see: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload

Comment: Check in `CKEDITOR.instances.editor_name.config` if you set configuration option properly.

Comment: Ok I got there in the end... if anyone else has a similar problem here's how to solve it: 1. Download ckfinder (there's a freee demo version) 2. download the example that uses ckfinder.  3. Then you have to edit the config file of ckfinder so that you can upload.  4. Then it will complain about not having an image editor so you have to change a value from "auto" to none in the ckfinder config file as well.